# unable to run nativescript locally

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I created a Nativescript-vue project with `tns create`
I think copied the files from my play.nativescript.org project:

> - app/
> - app.js
> - ..
> - components/
>     . -- Startup.vue
>     .   ---- folderOne/
>     .     ---- folderOneHome.vue
>     .   ---- folderTwo/
>     .     ---- folderTwoHome.vue

In my app.js I have:

```
import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
import Startup from "./components/Startup";

new Vue({

    template: `
        <Frame>
            <Startup />
        </Frame>`,

    components: {
        Startup
    }
}).$start();
```

But I run `tns preview` and get the following on my iPhone NativeScript Preview:

```
Executing before-preview-sync hook from /Users/xxxx/projects/private/myapp-mobile/hooks/before-preview-sync/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Start syncing changes for platform ios.
Copying template files...
Platform ios successfully added. v5.0.0
Executing before-shouldPrepare hook from /Users/xxxx/projects/private/myapp-mobile/hooks/before-shouldPrepare/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Preparing project...
Executing before-prepareJSApp hook from /Users/xxxx/projects/private/myapp-mobile/hooks/before-prepareJSApp/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Project successfully prepared (ios)
Executing after-prepare hook from /Users/xxxx/projects/private/myapp-mobile/hooks/after-prepare/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Successfully synced changes for platform ios.
LOG from device xxxx iPhone 8+: 2018-11-11 17:03:53.364 nsplaydev[4353:1286798] ***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
2018-11-11 17:03:53.364 nsplaydev[4353:1286798] Native stack trace:
1   0x100ffff84 NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool, bool)
2   0x1010386bc -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:]
3   0x100d18154 -[UIApplication(PlayLiveSync) swizzled_executeModule:]
4   0x1007b34f4
5   0x1d6ac2bb4 <redacted>
2018-11-11 17:03:53.365 nsplaydev[4353:1286798] JavaScript stack trace:
2018-11-11 17:03:53.365 nsplaydev[4353:1286798] 1   resolveSync@[native code]
2   @[native code]
3   promiseReactionJob@[native code]
2018-11-11 17:03:53.365 nsplaydev[4353:1286798] JavaScript error:
[native code]: JS ERROR Error: Could not find module './components/Startup'. Computed path '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/15C2D576-AEE0-40C4-A8FF-430289A66882/Documents/Playground/LiveSync/app/components/Startup'.
2018-11-11 17:03:53.366 nsplaydev[4353:1286798] PlayLiveSync: Uncaught Exception
2018-11-11 17:03:53.366 nsplaydev[4353:1286798] *** JavaScript call stack:
(

)
2018-11-11 17:03:53.366 nsplaydev[4353:1286798] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Error: Could not find module './components/Startup'. Computed path '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/15C2D576-AEE0-40C4-A8FF-430289A66882/Documents/Playground/LiveSync/app/components/Startup'.
 at
1   resolveSync@[native code]
2   @[native code]
3   promiseReactionJob@[native code]
```

When I run this online, I get my initial screen (Startup.vue) but not when I run it locally.  Do I need to write Sidekick differently than Play for something like this?

If it matters, I upgraded to NativeScript 5.0.

Also, I notice that when using Visual Studio Code, the autocomplete also doesn't find my ./components/Startup.vue but it does find all the subdirectories under ./components.

**Update**:
I created a new project via:  `vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template newTest`
then I cd into that directory and did `tns preview` and get the same error type:

> JS ERROR Error: Could not find module './components/App'.

So this appears NOT to be related to any project but rather with how this is being assembled?

Comment: Strange, did you try building the app instead?

Comment: I am able to do "tns build ios" without issues (but the path issue above still happens).  When I build in Sidekick I get the error: "Unexpectedly found two active proxied devices for companion dvtdevice-iphonesimulator:61ED0870-1FB6-45ED-BA6F-47C98DD0191D: dvtdevice-iphonesimulator:9B80"